# error en búsqueda binaria

Tags: c++

Intentaba resolver un problema usando búsqueda binaria y obtengo el siguiente error

**ISO C++ forbids comparision between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]**
dos veces en el siguiente codigo

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define MAX 100000
using namespace std;

    int binary_search(int *arr, int *array, int llaves)
    {
        int inicio= 0;
        int fin= llaves-1;
        int medio;

        while(inicio <= fin)
        {
            medio= (inicio+fin)/2;

            if(array == arr[medio])
            {
                return arr[medio];
            }
            else if(arr[medio] > array)
            {
                fin= medio-1;
            }
            else
            {
                inicio= medio+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int chapas, llaves;
        int arr[MAX];

        cin>>chapas;
        int array[chapas];
        for(int i=1; i<=chapas; i++)
        {
            cin>>array[i];
        }

        cin>>llaves;
        for(int i=1; i<=llaves; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }

        binary_search(arr, array, llaves);

        for(int i=1; i<=llaves; i++)
        {
            cout<<array[i];
        }
    }
```

he intendado muchas cosas y nada alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: cambia `array == arr[medio]` ---> `*array == arr[medio]`, lo mismo para `arr[medio] > array` ----> `arr[medio] > *array`

Answer (score 1):

El error es claro y conciso (y seguramente te marca la línea en que sucede) pero tal vez te cueste entenderlo por estar en inglés, lo traduzco:

> El estándar ISO C++ prohíbe la comparación entre punteros y enteros

Tal y como el error indica: estás comparando un puntero y un entero. Dicha comparación no tiene sentido porque aunque un puntero sea un número, conceptualmente son cosas diferentes.

Como analogía imagina la matrícula de un vehículo: tiene sentido saber qué matrícula es posterior o anterior a dicha matrícula pero no tiene sentido saber si dicha matrícula es mayor o menor a un número determinado.

---

En tu caso el error sucede en esta línea:

```
if(array == arr[medio])
```

La variable `array` es de tipo `int *` (puntero a entero) mientras que `arr[medio]` es de tipo `int` (entero). Así que estás comparando un puntero y un entero... cosa que no tiene sentido; según lo que necesites deberás comparar dos punteros:

```
if(array == &arr[medio])
//          ^ <--- Dirección de arr[medio]: es un puntero
```

O deberás comparar dos números:

```
if(*array == arr[medio])
// ^ <--- Contenido de array: es un número
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución ya te la a dado @eyllanesc. Tienes problemas manejando el puntero *arr en el scope de tu función. Recuerda que recibes un puntero a tu función, por lo tanto en este caso:

**arr** = "apunta" a una **dirección en memoria** donde esta alojado un tipo de dato entero.

***arr / arr[0]** = "apunta" al **dato entero** alojado en la dirección en memoria de arr.

Puedes buscar *manejo de apuntadores en funciones* para que te quede más claro, de paso conoces un poco más de como funciona la memoria. ¡Saludos!